# Desktop mono app and MVC/MVP framework

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, mono, mvp

I am looking for a MVC/MVP (mvp prefferably) framework for my first mono app.  There doesn't seem to be too much out there, but I have found the following:

http://www.mvcsharp.org/ http://desktoprails.osl.ull.es/doku.php

I've been looking into both for some time, and MVC# seems to be closer to what I want.

The issue is that MVC# seems to be a .net project and not designed specifically for mono (as opposed to desktop rails), so I'm not 100% sure how it will play with mono.  Also, it is under the Microsoft Public License (MsPL), and I am not sure how well that license will play with other components I intend to use that are gpl/mit/apache/etc.

So if anyone has any experience with either of these frameworks in mono and can answer any of these questions, I would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ASP.NET MVC Framework on Mono, that is to say

- You can host it using Apache2 and mod_mono
- You can develop it using MonoDevelop on Linux or MacOS (ASP.NET MVC is supported now)
  (You might have to install the ASP.NET MVC plugin for this, but that's easy)
  Of course this is only good for web applications, not desktop applications.